# Web scraping, reading data frames, and exporting to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping

The goal is to scrape pokemonDB, create a DataFrame of the Pokemon data; (Number, Name, Primary type, and secondary type), Separate the two types into their own rows, and export it as a CSV file.

I'm stuck on accessing the 'dex' dataframe, specifically the contents of the columns. Am I using ".loc" correctly?

And then there is separating the two types to each columns. I know i must use a space" " as a delimiter, but not sure how. I'm new to Pandas.

This is what i have:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

page = requests.get("https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all")

dex = pd.read_html(page.text, attrs = {'id': 'pokedex'}, index_col = '#')

column_label_list =  (list(dex[0].columns))

NationalNo = column_label_list[0];
Name = column_label_list[1];
Type = column_label_list[2];


numbers_list = dex.loc[ "#"]
names_list = dex.loc[ "Name"]
types1_list = dex.loc[ "Type"]


pokemon_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      NationalNo: numbers_list,
      Name: names_list,
      Type: types1_list,
      #'Type2': types2_list,
     })

print(pokemon_list)
#pokemon_list.to_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The result should look this like:

```
output.csv

# | Name    | Type1 | Type2 |
__|_________|_______|_______|
0 |Bulbasaur|Grass  |Poison |
__|_________|_______|_______|
.
.
.
etc...
```

I hope what I'm trying to accomplish makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dex` is an array of **all** tables existed on that HTML, since there is only one table, select the first table, then you don't need to map them to dataframe anymore, just export it directly since it's already a dataframe. Please consider using this code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

page = requests.get("https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all")

dex = pd.read_html(page.text, attrs = {'id': 'pokedex'}, index_col = '#')

dex[0].to_csv("output.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```